# Wordpress homepage dependent on user IP location

Tags: wordpress, geolocation, ip, subdomain, ip-geolocation

I'm currently running multisites in WordPress, and I'd like a user, when visiting domain.com to be directed to either city-x.domain.com or city-y.domain.com depending on which they are closer to depending on their rough location (IP address is close enough). Is this possible, and if so, where would I put the code?